# Add custom states for test runs in Quality Center

Tags: hp-quality-center

How do I add my own states in test runs? The default states are:

```
Passed, Failed, Blocked, N/A, Not Completed, No Run
```

I want to add e g "Passed with Failures".

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct permissions you can go to *Tools -> Customize...* to reach the Project Customization menu. From there go to *Project Lists -> Status* to view the list of existing statuses and to use *New Item* to add new statuses to the list.

You can tell which project list to look at for a given field by going to the field in *Project Entities*. In this case it is *Project Entities -> Test Instance -> System Fields -> Status* which then shows you the lookup list "Status". You could also use the *Goto List* button to jump directly to the linked project list.